# Windows 10 PC wireless suddenly low download ok speed phone and tablet rebooted etc already

Tags: performance, download, speed

My three month old PC Windows 10 on a wireless connection began to show slow download speed last week.  Now it crawls.  Tablet and Phone speed used a same location are fine.
I have rebooted turned the router off and on to no avail.  The wired PC windows 10 has not changed download speed.

There are not many apps running on this machine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring the speed? Can you let us know what Speedtest.net says? There are also Ookla Speedtest apps for Android and Apple Phones. Compare the readings between the devices.

Are the tablet and phone doing any kind of photo  cloud backups? Mobile devices can use quite a bit of bandwidth these days. Try turning the WiFi off on the phones and tablets and see if download speeds are better on the laptop. Remember to turn WiFi on again in the event you don't have much cellular data.

Also, if you use a cloud service like OneDrive or DropBox on the laptop try disabling it.

Also, if it possible try the internet from a coffee shop and see if it is slower or faster.